# Waiting for network connectivity instead of just sleep fixed time

Tags: raspbian, networking, script, bash, systemd

I'm new to the whole Raspberry Pi and Bash scripting thing, so bear with me.

I run raspberry autopilot on a remotely controlled vehicle thru a 3G/4G connection. Raspberry Pi is installed onboard the vehicle. It connects to an OpenVPN server, and sends UDP telemetry to a machine on the VPN network.

The 3G/4G coverage is not stable so I need to keep an eye on it. I have `crontab` script which runs every minute:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
        echo "Online $dt" >> /home/pi/navio-drone/keepalive.log
else
        dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
        # Timestamped message to log file
        echo "Offline $dt" >> /home/pi/navio-drone/keepalive.log
        # Disconnect  from OpenVPN
        echo $(date -u) "Stopping OpenVPN connection" >> /home/pi/navio-drone/keepalive.log
        systemctl stop openvpn@navio.service
        # Trigger power to USB ports to reset Huawei modem, 1 sec delay
        echo $(date -u) "Resetting USB modem connection" >> /home/pi/navio-drone/keepalive.log
        ./uhubctl -a 2 -l 1-1 -d 1
        # Sleep 45 sec (let modem to find network) and connect to OpenVPN server
        echo $(date -u) "Sleeping 45 seconds" >> /home/pi/navio-drone/keepalive.log
        sleep 45
        echo $(date -u) "Starting OpenVPN connection" >> /home/pi/navio-drone/keepalive.log
        systemctl start openvpn@navio.service
fi
```

How would you tidy up this script and specifically get rid of

```
`sleep 45`
```

in it? Sometimes it takes 30 sec, sometimes 50 for the modem to reconnect to network.

**EDIT #1**

My **ip addr** output(4G interface connected):

```
pi@navio:~ $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b3:46:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enxb827ebe613ef: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:e6:13:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: enx00a0c60429a0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:c6:04:29:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enx00a0c60429a0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::240e:3007:3e42:4e64/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 192.168.30.17 peer 192.168.30.18/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8604:8c6b:e6f1:e9d7/64 scope link flags 800
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My **ip route** output(4G interface connected):

```
pi@navio:~ $ ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.30.18 dev tun0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enx00a0c60429a0 src 192.168.1.100 metric 211
116.203.32.50 via 192.168.1.1 dev enx00a0c60429a0
128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.30.18 dev tun0
192.168.1.0/24 dev enx00a0c60429a0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100 metric 211
192.168.30.18 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.30.17
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to give some specific hints because there is no information about the network setup. But usually you can check if an interface is online. There is a tool from *systemd* that can check it:

```
rpi ~$ /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --help
systemd-networkd-wait-online [OPTIONS...]

Block until network is configured.

  -h --help                 Show this help
     --version              Print version string
  -q --quiet                Do not show status information
  -i --interface=INTERFACE  Block until at least these interfaces have appeared
     --ignore=INTERFACE     Don't take these interfaces into account
     --timeout=SECS         Maximum time to wait for network connectivity
```

You can look with `ip addr` what interfaces available and what interface has to be online after resetting the USB modem connection. I don't know if the tool detects the interface for the 4G connection but it is worth a try. Just replace the `sleep 45` statement for example with:

```
sudo /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=wlan0 --timeout=120 --quiet
```

That returns immediately when the interface **wlan0** gets online or with an error after 120 seconds. It does not stress the CPU when waiting like a busy loop.

**Update:**
Here are yet another two possibilities. In `/sys/class/net/$NETINTERFACE/carrier` the kernel shows if the interface has got a carrier. With a bash function you can test it:

```
#!/bin/bash

function has-carrier {
    MAX_ATTEMPTS=30
    attempt_num=1
    until [ $(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier) -eq 1 ] || [ $attempt_num -eq $MAX_ATTEMPTS ]; do
        echo attempt $attempt_num: no carrier
        ((attempt_num++))
        sleep 3
    done

    if [ $attempt_num -eq $MAX_ATTEMPTS ]; then
        echo attempt $attempt_num: timeout
        exit 1
    else
        echo attempt $attempt_num: carrier
        exit 0
    fi
}

has-carrier
```

This function will check the carrier every 3 seconds for 30 attempts. After 90 seconds (3 sec * 30 attempts) it will timeout.

Then there is a daemon `ifplugd` that may be usable. It mainly checks wired ethernet ports but it also has a feature:

> - Configure WLAN devices (on detecting a successful association to an AP)

Check with `apt show ifplugd`.

Comment: `/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=enx00a0c60429a0 --timeout=120 --quiet`

times out with error while interface is up. Is that a correct behavior?

Comment: btw, this interface state is **unknown** when checked with `ip addr`

Comment: @user95138 Please edit your question and add the output from `ip addr` and from `ip route` when a 4G connection is established. When testing you can also omit option `--quiet` to see messages.

Comment: Fixed the question. The output without quiet is just “ignoring: lo” which probably means it ignores loopback interface.

Comment: @user95138 Try to prefix the command with `sudo`. I have updated my answer with it. I've just looked at the tool and it seems it only checks for `gained carrier`. You can find this status in `journalctl -b` (or even not). I'm looking at it, just a moment ...

Comment: when run with `sudo` it says it is ignoring my other interfaces: lo, tun0, enxb827ebe613ef. Still times out with `Event loop failed: Connection timed out
`

Comment: Also any ideas with ping and timeout do not work. Ping just immidiately exits with network is unreachable error.

Comment: @VladimirP Just see your ping test. I have also updated my answer with another two tests.

Answer (score 2):

Replaced it with:

```
sleep 10 # Not going to be faster than 10sec anyway
echo $(date) "Waiting for network to recover" 
itest=$(ping -c 1 -W 2 116.203.32.50 | grep "1 packets transmitted, 1 received")
while [ "$itest" == "" ]
do
   sleep 2
   itest=$(ping -c 1 -W 2 116.203.32.50 | grep "1 packets transmitted, 1 received")
done
echo $(date) "Connected to cellular network"
```